# Escape double quotes when converting a dict to json in Python

Tags: python, json

I need to escape double quotes when converting a dict to json in Python, but I'm struggling to figure out how.

So if I have a dict like `{'foo': 'bar'}`, I'd like to convert it to json and escape the double quotes - so it looks something like:

`'{\"foo\":\"bar\"}'`

`json.dumps` doesn't do this, and I have tried something like:

`json.dumps({'foo': 'bar'}).replace('"', '\\"')` which ends up formatting like so:

`'{\\"foo\\": \\"bar\\"}'`

This seems like such a simple problem to solve but I'm really struggling with it.

Comment: If you escape the double quotes, *it's not JSON*. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'm trying to use requests to send some data to an endpoint. The endpoint requires data to be formatted with escaped double quotes *sigh*

Comment: Are you trying to swap out single and double quotes for string inclusion?

Comment: @SunnyPatel no, I don't think so. I literally want to escape double quotes in a json object. `'{\"escape\": \"quotes\"}'`

Comment: Make sure you use [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) to actually see what's being properly escaped. Just try out different numbers of escaped slashes `\\` to get your result. You're on the right track.

Comment: If your broken endpoint is expecting JSON strings’ quotes to be escaped, what it is expecting to get for actual escaped quotes in the middle of a string? Or is that just not an issue because you’ll never have such values and if you did the broken server would just segfault anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure why I got downvoted here. My question is pretty clear as to what I want to do, and other details relating to an endpoint to which I have no control over are irrelevant.

Comment: It seems as if I was completely wrong on this - the endpoint is working as expected I was just not getting expected return data. I will flag for deletion as the question is superfluous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your last attempt `json.dumps({'foo': 'bar'}).replace('"', '\\"')` is actually correct for what you think you want.

The reason you see this:

```
'{\\"foo\\": \\"bar\\"}'
```

Is because you're printing the representation of the string. The string itself will have only a single backslash for each quote. If you use `print()` on that result, you will see a single backslash

Answer (score 0):

What you have does work. Python is showing you the literal representation of it. If you save it to a variable and print it shows you what you're looking for.

```
>>> a = json.dumps({'foo': 'bar'}).replace('"', '\\"')
>>> print a
{\"foo\": \"bar\"}
>>> a
'{\\"foo\\": \\"bar\\"}'
```